# Eigenvalues sorted in numpy.eig and scipy.eig in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to obtain the eigenvalues of a matrix with the function of `scipy` and `numpy` but these function returns the eigenvalues listed in decreasing order, I need them as associated to the row/column of the matrix, so the i-th eigenvalue has to be the one associated with the i-th raw/column of the matrix and NOT the i-th biggest one.

Comment: What is an eigenvalue associated with a row?

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvaules are not associated with a row or column, but they ara associated with an Eigenvector, in a way that a matrix multiplication of Eigenvector and original matrix is the same as a scalar multiplication with the corresponding Eigenvalue:

```
A * v = k * v
```

with `A` the matrix, `v` the Eigenvector and `k` the (scalar) Eigenvalue.

The order in which you arrive at the Eigenvalues is arbitrary, since during you hand-calculation, you can switch and swap rows and columns arbitrarily to determine the determinant (to compute the Eigenvalues).